# SWT: Get system image for "settings" (cog?)

Tags: java, swt

I would like to make it as native as possible.
So I need a possibility to get system icons.

The only thing I can find on this is how to get dialog icons like `SWT.ICON_ERROR` and so on.
Is there a chance to get other system icons like open, save, copy, and so on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently not possible with SWT.

There is a bug report [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=93606).

---

What you can do however, is use the Eclipse icons which can be found [here](http://eclipse-icons.i24.cc/). There is also a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15921149/java-element-icons-swt-eclipse).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok thanks. I don't want to use Eclipse icons as the application should be independent. But thanks anyway. Then I need to use a custom image.